# build a file.lib to a file.a usable on linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I'm trying to port a api from windows to linux. So far I've done the work on file.cpp and file.h but I still have a library .lib specified to windows that is needed in order for the api to work. how can I build a file.a usable on linux from this library?

Comment: You can't port compiled binaries like that. Except maybe with some really big effort or specialized tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static libraries in Linux (or all POSIX systems, like Mac OSX) are actually archives containing all object files. These archives are created with the [`ar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) command:

```
ar crv some_library.a some_object_file.o
```

The above command creates the "archive" (i.e. static library) `some_library.a` from the object file `some_object_file.o`. This library can now be used when linking other programs.

Comment: sorry, but how am I using my file.lib to generate these? I'm new in linux.

Comment: @SamuelNLP You don't, you need the object files used to generate the original library file. However, you can't use the files compiled for Windows, you need to compile the sources _on_ the Linux machine.

Comment: @SamuelNLP Either that (if and only if they were built for Linux), or the source.

Comment: well, if I have the source can you give me a hint on how to proceed then? I'm kind of lost.

Comment: @SamuelNLP Google is your friend... If it's a third-party library search for build instructions for that library (or as a vendor if it's vendor supplied), else search for how to create "makefiles" and general Linux/UNIX/POSIX compiling tutorials.

Comment: @Royi No. Files compiled for a specific target system (with one OS and using some specific CPU) will not be usable on another target (different OS or CPU).