# Is it possible to extract a object file from a file.lib?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [build a file.lib to a file.a usable on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877196/build-a-file-lib-to-a-file-a-usable-on-linux)

As I say in the title is it possible to extract a object file from a file.lib. The point of this is to then create the file.a so I can compile the ported file.cpp I ported from windows to linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lib /extract` to invoke the librarian and extract object files out of a lib. However, note that you can't just pack Windows-generated object files into a `.a` archive and expect them to work on Linux. When porting across platforms, you have to recompile *from source.*

Comment: meaning that then it worthless to extract them. I have to contact the creator of the .file.lib to request the source.

Comment: Is there a way to reapck object files from different `lib` files into single `lib` file? For instance compact all OpenCV static libraries into single file?

Comment: @Royi Sure. Extract them using `lib /extract` from all the libs and then repack them into one using normal `lib` operation.